# Set start time of Timer Interval

Tags: vb.net, timer

how do i set the starting time of the time interval, let's say i would like to start the 5 sec interval counting after 10 seconds. I'm having a problem with my logic can you help me with this? this is my code:

This is my timer in my `Form1`

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

If DateTime.Now = Form3.DateTimePicker1.Value Then
        Timer2.Stop()
        MsgBox("hey")
        Timer2.Start()
    End If
```

This is the **OK** button in my `Form3`

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Form1.Timer2.Interval = New TimeSpan(CInt(NumericUpDown3.Value), CInt(NumericUpDown2.Value), CInt(NumericUpDown1.Value)).TotalMilliseconds
        Form1.Timer2.Start()
    End If
```

It seems to work successfully with the intervals without setting the start of the interval, But if i add the start time of the interval, it doesn't seem to work. with this code `If DateTime.Now = Form3.DateTimePicker1.Value Then` what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be bad idea:

```
 If DateTime.Now = Form3.DateTimePicker1.Value Then
```

Because it is *extremely hard* for you to catch the time *exactly* as you specify. Simply change `=` to `>=`

```
If DateTime.Now >= Form3.DateTimePicker1.Value Then
```

Then when you reach the time *or* later, you would show your message box.

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot! i've wasted hours for this.